# How to measure CPU time of a process in C?

Tags: c, unix-timestamp

I would like to measure the CPU and User time passed between starting a process and sending `SIGINT` signal using C `times` function.

However, on print I just get `0`. Can't see the problem..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <signal.h> 

struct tms time_start;
struct tms time_end;

clock_t start;
clock_t end; 

void handle() { 
    times(&time_end);
    end = time_end.tms_stime;
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 

    signal(SIGINT, handle);
    times(&time_start);
    start = time_start.tms_utime;
    pause(); 
    printf("end: %ld, start: %ld\n", (long) end, (long) start);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
k@sc:dir$ ./my_time
^Cend: 0, start: 0
```

Comment: `end` has type `clock_t`, you're printing a `long` with `"%ld"`. I'd convert ... `printf("%ld\n", (long)end);` ... "clock_t shall be an integer or real-floating type"

Comment: @TMOTTM Could you please remove line numbers from your code snippet? Could you please include the relevant `#include` headers in your source and remove the additional empty lines? Side note: calling `printf` from a signal handler is not allowed.

Comment: I adjusted it and pasted a second version

Answer (score 0):

> on print I just get 0. Can't see the problem..

The `tms_stime` is the CPU time spend in the kernel on behalf of the process. `pause()` is doing nothing, so it doesn't count for CPU time, `signal` and `times` are not computationally demanding functions - your program is doing nothing. Do some I/O operations, get that kernel to work to see some changes in times.

For example the following program reads 400000000 bytes from `/dev/urandom`:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct tms time_end;

void handle() {
    times(&time_end);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    signal(SIGINT, handle);

    // read from urandom so that kernel has to generate randomness
    FILE *f = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; ++i) {
        char buf[20];
        fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, f);
    }
    fclose(f);

    pause();

    printf("tms_stime = %ld\n", (long)time_end.tms_stime);
    return 0;
}
```

Saved as `1.c` file and executed on my system in shell outputs:

```
$ sh -c 'gcc 1.c ; ./a.out & child=$!; sleep 2; kill -INT $child ; wait'
tms_stime = 127
```

On linux there is also `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` you might be interested in.